# Automaticly add 3rd pary jars to Tomcat's lib folder

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jar, buildpath

I'm using Eclipse Neon 4.6 and Tomcat 8.  I have my deployment assembly set with external jars via user libs and dependent projects.  When I clean and build the project only the dependent project's jar files are added to Tomcat's WEB-INF/lib folder, not the 3rd party external jars even though they are specified in user libs and the lib is in the deployment descriptor.  Any ideas as to why Tomcat isn't automatically coping the user lib jar files?  One interesting note is that if I put the jar files in the project's WEB-INF/lib folder they are not picked up at run time either.  I have also tried adding WEB-INF/lib to the deployment descriptor without any luck.

Comment: Are you seriously managing dependencies manually? Use Maven or alike.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this.  Turns out I correctly had libraries as dependencies in the project but did not mark them for export in Project | properties | Java build path | Order and Export.  I had to check the libs for export.  Now they are included in the WEB-INF/lib folder when I create the project WAR file.